# In powershell, how do i Apply a command action?

Tags: windows, powershell, network-share

I have a file screen configured with a notification to write an event to the event log. I also want to configure that same file screen, using power shell, to run a power shell script. **Does anyone know how I can add an action to a file screen template or a file screen??**

I used the following to create my event notification action.

`$EventNotification = New-FsrmAction Event -EventType Warning -Body $EventMessage`

Then the following to add it to my File screen template:

```
New-FsrmFileScreenTemplate -Name $fileTemplateName -IncludeGroup Group1,Group2 -Active: $true -Notification $EventNotification
```

But when I create an action to run my power shell script I cannot figure out how to add it to the template, or just a file screen.

This is what I am using currently, how do i apply it to a template or file screen?

```
$CommandAction = new-fsrmAction -Type Command -Command $PowerShellPath -CommandParameters $cmdparam
```

**Additional info:**

```
$PowerShellPath =
    C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

$cmdparam =
        c:\scripts\script00113.ps1
```

Comment: I may have found my answer: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/how-do-you-do/159149-cryptolocker-prevention-3.html  `$command = New-FsrmAction Command -Command "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"-CommandParameters "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command &{C:\Disconnect-SMBShares.ps1 -username '[Source Io Owner]'}" -SecurityLevel LocalSystem -KillTimeOut 5 -RunLimitInterval 0
`

Comment: If this worked for you please update the question with the answer below. You are free to answer your own questions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer at this link http://www.edugeek.net/forums/how-do-you-do/159149-cryptolocker-prevention-3.html

```
$command = New-FsrmAction Command -Command "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"-‌​CommandParameters "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -command &{C:\Disconnect-SMBShares.ps1 -username '[Source Io Owner]'}" -SecurityLevel LocalSystem -KillTimeOut 5 -RunLimitInterval 0
```